# fill column with last value from partition in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'm trying to return the last value of a partition and apply it to the rest of the column

For example, if I have the below...

```
ID    Date      Status
1     20150101
1     20150201
1     20150301
1     20150401  void
2     20150101
2     20150201
2     20150301
```

I want to return this.

```
ID    Date      Status
1     20150101   void
1     20150201   void
1     20150301   void
1     20150401   void
2     20150101
2     20150201
2     20150301
```

I've been playing around with the below and similar to no avail.

```
select 
ID, 
date, 
case when status is null then last_value(status ignore nulls) 
over (partition by id order by id, date) else status end as status
from table
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT id, date, last_value(status) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date) AS stat
FROM table;
```