# Generate missing data and fill it down - postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have the dataset:
[image]

The problem is that the records are added only if an event happened, e.g. for the row with id 13897, the record was updated on 4/18/2020 and then on 5/1/2020 - the status was changed. What I need is the status of each record at the end of every month.

[image]

I was thinking about the below logic:

1. generate the series of dates from the min(date) till now - T1
2. get distinct id from the dataset - T2
3. do cross join between two above tables so that we get a new row for every row in the second table - T3
4. extract the dataset with all required fields  - T4
5. merge T3 and T4 by concatenate(date and id) - T5
6. sort T5 by id and d asc - T5
7. fill-down all the fields grouped by id - T5
8. generate the series of dates from min(date) till now with the interval of one month  and get the  last day of each month - T6
9. merge T5 and T6 by date - right join so that we get only rows with the date = end of month

I am on step 6.

```
SELECT    * 
FROM      (SELECT     d, Concat(dt, t2.id) AS cnct 
                     FROM       (SELECT d,d::date AS dt 
                                       FROM   generate_series( 
                                              ( SELECT min(created_at::date) 
                                                     FROM   new_table), CURRENT_DATE , interval '1 day') d) t1 
                     CROSS JOIN 
                                (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM new_table )) t2)t3 
--in case if a record with the same id was updated several times throughout the day
LEFT JOIN (WITH cte AS 
          ( SELECT   id, status, created_at at  time zone 'eat' at time zone 'utc' AS "created_at", updated_at::date AS date, updated_at::date, row_number() OVER (partition BY id, updated_at::date ORDER BY updated_at DESC)  rnFROM     new_table ))SELECT cte.*,  Concat(updated_at::date, id) AS cnct 
 FROM   cte 
 WHERE  rn = 1) t4 
   ON     t3.cnct = t4.cnct
```

I am stuck on step 7. I found [fill column with last value from partition in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956967/fill-column-with-last-value-from-partition-in-postgresql) but it is not what I need. I envision that I need to sort by a date block i.e. dates from min date to now for one id - 13894 are to be considered block 1, dates from min date to now for another id - 13897 are to be considered block 2. The next step I thought is to fill-down all fields per a block.

And another question, how do you deal with the event-based data to adapt it for the time-series?

[image]

Tried:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Postgresql's DISTINCT ON feature to do this. We'll generate a series with the start of every month (you'll need to supply start and end dates here) and put the ID and the date into the DISTINCT ON so that we get only one row of new_table for each distinct ID and month pair. Then we simply filter and order to ensure that the row we're getting for each ID and month is the latest row for which the date is before the new month.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (new_table.id, month_start) *
FROM new_table, generate_series(start_date, end_date, interval '1 month') month_start
WHERE new_table.date < month_start
ORDER BY new_table.id, month_start ASC, new_table.date DESC;
```

(If you need your results to have the last day of the month and not the first day of the next month, you can just subtract 1 day from month_start in your select clause.)

EDIT: Running on the data you supplied, I get this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (new_table.id, month_start) new_table.id, month_start - interval '1 day' as month_end, new_table.status 
FROM new_table, generate_series('2020-05-01', '2020-06-01', interval '1 month') month_start 
WHERE new_table.date < month_start 
ORDER BY new_table.id, month_start ASC, new_table.date DESC;
  id   |       month_end        | status
-------+------------------------+--------
 13894 | 2020-04-30 00:00:00-07 |      5
 13894 | 2020-05-31 00:00:00-07 |      5
 13897 | 2020-04-30 00:00:00-07 |      2
 13897 | 2020-05-31 00:00:00-07 |      5
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Tried but the result for 13897 is not correct - the status is 2 while for month 4 it is 2 and for month 5 it should be 5 - see the initial dataset.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I inputted the rows in your example and it worked fine for me, see my edit.

Comment: I apologize, Genious - not sarcastic. Apparently, for testing, I modified new_table.... and your query works as expected and it is like 5 times shorter than mine..